# Как отправить POST из HTML в Python

Tags: python

Это самый нубский вопрос, но везде пишут о том, как отправить запрос ИЗ python, а мне нужен аналог $_POST из php.

Comment: Это зависит от того HTTP-сервера или веб-фреймворка, который вы используете в питоне

Comment: Я не использую фреймворков, а сервер- Apache 2.4

Comment: И как к этому Apache 2.4 подключен питон?

Comment: просто установлен, а подключается в py файле через строку cо ссылкой на python.exe

Comment: CGI что ли? Лучше тогда для начала выберите другой способ, CGI устаревшая и очень медленная технология

Comment: CGI ? на дворе 2017 год, используйте wsgi интерфейс, к серверу Apache 2.4 можно подключить с помощью модуля wsgi_mod, но более универсальная связка это wsgi + uwsgi + nginx. И через переменную окружения, используя wsgi, там вам и POST и GET и PATH  и COOKIE и вообще, что душе угодно ) Да, и все же рекомендую использовать какой либо микро фреймворк, очень хорошо себя зарекомендовал Flask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В комменте я и Игорь Игоряныч уже упомянули, что CGI это не очень хорошо, но если уж хочется его использовать:

Python в стандартной библиотеке содержит модуль `cgi`, в котором есть пачка утилит, полезных для CGI-скриптов. Одной из этих утилит является класс `FieldStorage`, который парсит `sys.stdin` как HTTP POST данные и предоставляет аналог PHP'шного `$_POST`; подробнее про его использование можно почитать в [справке](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html), а я приведу простой пример получения текстового значения:

```
import cgi

print('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')
print()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()  # form — приблизительный аналог $_POST

# Проверка, есть ли data в форме вообще. Если нет, то предполагаем,
# что это GET-запрос, и отдаём HTML-код формы
if 'data' not in form:
    print('''
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Введите какой-нибудь текст:<br/>
            <input name="data" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
        </form>
    ''')

# Проверка на непустое значение. getlist возвращает список всех
# data из формы; в нашей форме только один data и мы берём первый
# и единственный элемент из списка
elif form.getlist('data')[0]:
    print('Вы ввели: <strong>{escaped_data}</strong>'.format(
        # не забываем про уязвимости XSS; используем cgi.escape,
        # чтобы экранировать HTML-спецсимволы и защититься
        escaped_data=cgi.escape(form.getlist('data')[0], quote=True)
    ))

else:
    print('Вы ничего не ввели')
```

И всё же так делать плохо, лучше возьмите Flask <sub><sup>(или сразу Sanic, слава асинхронщине)</sup></sub>

Comment: У flask можно [включить threaded](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6f0c0a960fbf0900042dc0b4c494de21bc3cd386/web_servers/hello_world/main.py#L32) и тогда он асихронным :)

Comment: @gil9red асинхронность, в отличие от многопоточности, может использовать и чаще всего использует строго один поток